# find string line startswith recursively python

Tags: python, startswith

i have to find recursively all lines( which start with string "excel") in all files (in directory and subdirectory) .i need for each filename the line found (for example :
 filename1: 
line1 founded...
filename2:

line2 founded...
Output result in file called "logfile"
if no line founded , filename not saved in logfile.

```
import os
word="excel"
from os.path import join
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('/batch/'):
    for filename in files:
      thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
         for line in files: 
           if line.startswith(word):
                    print (line)
                    print (thefile)
```

Thanks

Comment: and? what is this code? does it work, or not? if not, why not?

Comment: recursively: don't you need a function calling itself then?

Comment: I think the operation of `os.walk` is meant: it traverses a directory tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just has minor problems: The biggest one is that you loop on filename instead of file content.

```
import os
word="excel"
from os.path import join
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('/batch/'):
    for filename in files:
        thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        with open(thefile) as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith(word):
                    print (line)
                    print (thefile)
```

EDIT:

```
import os
word="excel"
from os.path import join
with open('log_result.txt', 'w') as log_file:
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('/tmp/toto'):
        for filename in files:
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            with open(thefile) as f:
                lines = [line for line in f if line.startswith(word)]
            if lines:
                log_file.write("File {}:\n".format(thefile))
                log_file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: this code works perfectly.Last thing,for result how can i put the lines found under the same filename ?For example :
filename
 all lines found

filename2
result...

redirect these to a file called "Logresult.txt".
thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi Django, thanks for your quick reply.The result is correct but i need only filenames (and lines) which contains the word "excel" (not all filenames)....

Comment: I adapt my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code. 
you don't need to re traverse the same list of files.
os.walk() will return all sub directories  in a directory, All you need you do is loop all directories.

**Sample Code**

```
import glob
import os
word="excel"

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk("/batch/"):
    for file_ in files :
        if  file_.startswith(word):
                print(file_)
                print(os.path.join(dirname, file_))

    for dir_ in dirs :
        myfiles  = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname,dir_))
        for myfile in myfiles:
            if  myfile.startswith(word):
                    print(myfile)
                    print(os.path.join(dirname,myfiles))
```

hope this helps